# is it possible to update the service fabric manifest?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy-configure-secure-communication) tutorial, and would like to change the **fabricsettings** setting:

[image]

I would like to change it to something like this:

```
{
"fabricSettings": [
          ...
          {
            "name": "ApplicationGateway/Http",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "ApplicationCertificateValidationPolicy",
                "value": "None"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        ...
}
```

**How do you change the manifest settings on service fabric?**